# how do i move data from one column into another column in same table with different data type in cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have a varchar column in a cassandra table which I want to move to a different column with data type as set.  What's the best way to do it ?
Both columns are in the same table.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it 2 ways:

1. Use [Spark Cassandra connector](https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector) to perform batch read, transformation of date & write data back - this is very optimal if you have cluster of several machines, because processing could be parallelized;
2. Write your own code (for example, in Python) that will iterate over the whole ring, read data, transform & write them back. You can use CQL like: `select * from ks.table where token(partition_key) > start_range AND token(partition_key) <= end_range)`, and ranges you can get via `Cluster.metadata.ring`...